# Why cant I experience the slowdown of page loads within browser during a cloud based load test?

Tags: cloud, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I'm running a cloud based load test with 20,000 users. The average page time is about 40secs but I cannot experience this slowdown while navigating through browser, why is this?

Comment: Rather than the averages, look at the percentile values. These shows that 90% of pages (and other percentages) were quicker than the indicated values.

Answer (score 0):

The average could be influenced by a small number of very high values. For example, if 99% of pages are less than 5 seconds then, statistically speaking, you'd have to hit the page 100 times before you'd see the slow page. Realistically, it could require much more.  You'll need to dig deeper than the average to determine this (plot the individual response times, standard deviation, etc).

It's also possible that the difference is due to something environmental that makes your session more responsive (network routing, browser version, caching, DNS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If the average page loading time from the test tool is this long (40secs) but your browser doesn't feel slow, then I would check the test tool to see if it's the bottleneck.

Note that many test tools themselves will be very slow when emulating a large number of clients. You may want to check the CPU usage of the test tool by

- On linux or Mac, you can run command "top -c"
- on Windows, you can run task manager.

  I am sure there are other means of check the CPU usage of the test tool as well.

If you identify the test tool to be the bottleneck, you either need to emulate less clients on one tool (so you have more running instances of the tool to build up 20,000 clients) or choose a different test tool.  You may consider [Netgend](http://www.netgend.com) test platform. Which can emulate 50,000 HTTPS clients and 1,000,000 HTTP clients.

Good luck.